# Solar charger module for two NiMH in series

Tags: solar-cell, charging, nimh

I have two 2450mAh NiMH batteries to be used to power an IOT project outdoors. I would like to charge the batteries with a solar panel, 5V, 1W. I have come across [this module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004058681496.html?pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22:%2212000027894281234%22,%22ship_from%22:%22%22%7D&gps-id=pcStoreJustForYou&scm=1007.23125.137358.0&scm_id=1007.23125.137358.0&scm-url=1007.23125.137358.0&pvid=733c49b3-0d2e-40ad-a023-fbccf0a37a87&spm=a2g0o.store_pc_home.smartJustForYou_6000950734800.0) for which specs for 2 cell charger is

```
Input voltage : DC 4.5V-5.5V(Recommend DC 5V)
Charging voltage about : 2.7V-3.4V
Charging current about :230mA-240mA
```

I need advice on below
The module must work fine since the charging current is less than .1C (0.1*2450)
The output can be taken from the battery terminal on the module ( Why I am asking this is to make sure that I can use battery while charging)
Is it safe to keep the batteries under share where the temperature is somewhere around 35°C?

Thanks
Ranjith

Comment: Welcome! Schematic or block diagram please!

Comment: To me it is not clear that the module will stop charging at the correct voltage. I recommend 2.88V for 2 NiMH cells in series.

Comment: You can't use the battery while charging. Current either goes into the battery or comes out of it, but not both.